# XML datatype in SQL Server and LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, drop-down-menu, sqlxml

I want to retrieve the XML data from SQL Server database and bound it to the DropDownList using LINQ query on C#.

XML field in clients table:

```
<root>
  <clientname>andrew</clientname> --  dropdownlist text field
  <clientid>1</clientid>          -- dropdownlist value field
  <clientname>jim</clientname>
  <clientid>2</clientid>
  <clientname>john</clientname>
  <clientid>3</clientid>
  <clientname>johnson</clientname>
  <clientid>4<clientid>
</root>
```

do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ (presumably meaning LINQ-to-SQL or EF) doesn't currently have any special treatment of the XML data-type. You'll need to fetch it back as normal, then load it into a DOM and handle from there. Perhaps looking at the question: [how to load xml file into dropdownlist in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987359/how-to-load-xml-file-into-dropdownlist-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you store list of entities as one value.
Try to normalize your DB model.